# Typo3 6.0 - TCA - news - hide certain types of news in select field

Tags: configuration, typo3, hide, tx-news

I am new to typo3, and I need help concerning the News extension and the $TCA configuration.

I have made an extension called "Activité" which extends from News. This went pretty well. I created some custom fields and I was able to make my extension "selectable" from the select field already available in the "General" tab.

All I want to do is to hide the default selectable fields already there (in this case, I want to hide "Internal page" and "External page".

It seems so simple, but I want to do this the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not write what news extension you use. For old one tt_news you disable by

```
TCEFORM.tt_news.type.removeItems = 1,2
```

for new one "news" by

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.type.removeItems = 1,2
```

General syntax is:

```
TCEFORM.[table_name].[field_name].[action]
```

For example you can completyl disable not used fields with

```
TCEFORM.[table_name].[field_name].disabled = 1
```

You can also set default values to fields with syntax

```
TCAdefaults.[table_name].[field_name] = value
```

You should add this typoscript in page propertes. Tab "Resources", field TypoScript Configuration / Page TSConfig.

Comment: thank you! this is going to help me so much! (I am using the "news" extension, not tt_news.) this is perfect thanks